# Можно ли на флексбоксах сделать неравномерную плитку?

Tags: css

Есть блоки как на картинке. Можно ли на флексбоксах сверстать такие блоки, не оборачивая .promo и .blog в отдельный div ?

[image]

Comment: я как не пробую, даже когда задаю для .blog размер 1 на 1 пиксель, он все равно падает под блок .sidebar, он не хочет идти в свободное пространство как на картинке

Comment: Не оборачивая - нельзя.

Comment: какой в этом смысл? у вас 3 логические секции: `header, main, footer`, `main` делится на `section` и `aside`

Comment: в условиях, описанных вами, нельзя